# Heroku wrong credentials for postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

i’m using heroku for deploy a database (postgres) and connect to it.
I used it for 2 weeks but today it start rejecting my credential and i couldn’t login anymore, i checked if the credential are changed but nothing?
Can anyone help me? thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable every time you connect?

Comment: I used the url they give me in the settings of database and it works for two weeks if i try to connect to database with datagrip it give me an error with credentials too @Chris

Comment: I'm not familiar with DataGrip. It looks like a database IDE? What is the specific error that you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, if you look in the Settings -> Config Vars you will see that the `DATABASE_URL` has changed. So you need to use the new value in Datagrip and things will work again.
They change the details periodically but it doesn't seem to update in the database settings page which is very annoying although it only happens on the free tier.

Comment: To get an updated DATABASE_URL do the `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` with the heroku-cli,